# React - mapping async data to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, promise

I have an API get request here, being called on mount in my useEffect hook and then set

```
const [multilineAccountInfo, setMultilineAccountInfo] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getMultilineAccountInfo();
    return () => {
      console.log('cleanup home/balance');
    };
  }, []);

const getMultilineAccountInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get('Account/MultiLineAllAccountsInfo')
      .then(response => {
        let parse_response = JSON.parse(response.data);
        let stringified_data = JSON.stringify(parse_response);
        setMultilineAccountInfo(stringified_data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('getMultilineAccountInfo error', error);
      });
  };
```

The problem that I'm facing is that in my View here, the app crashes and says "undefined is not a function (near '...multilineAccountInfo.map...')"

```
const MultilineDetailHome = multilineAccountInfo.map((item, index) => (
    <View key={index}>
      <View style={styles.multilineCards}>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.multilineNameText}>
              {item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.multilinePhoneText}>
              {formatPhoneNumber(item.Pnum)}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{marginLeft: hp('3%')}}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.multilineBalanceText}>
                ${item.Balance.toFixed(2)}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.multilineTypeText}>{item.AccountType}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  ));
```

I am pretty sure this is happening because of the async nature of setState() and the data not being returned in time before the .map() method is invoked.

How would I go about waiting for the API call to finish before the .map() and finally rendering the View in the UI?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem while loading data, you can use this:

```
multilineAccountInfo.length > 0 ? YOUR COMPONENT : <h1>LOADING</h1>
```

another way can be using another state like:

```
[isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

and then setting it after your `async` method.

```
.then(response => {
        let parse_response = JSON.parse(response.data);
        let stringified_data = JSON.stringify(parse_response);
        setMultilineAccountInfo(stringified_data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
```

now You can use it in your component rendering section:

```
isLoading? Text("Loading"):YOUR COMPONENT
```